# Getting all expirations for options chain in IB API

Tags: python, finance

I am looking for a way to get all the existing expiration dates for option chains. I copied the following code sample from the IB short video series on YouTube. I'm having 2 issues:

1. I am confused by the OOP structure used (class and methods) and can't figure out how to feed in for example a Stock ticker and then return the possible expirations as a list. I would preferably have a function that takes as inputs (Ticker, Contract ID) and returns (list of expiration dates)
2. How can I figure out the contract ID from the inputs ("AAPL","STK") for example? do I need additional information on the contract?

This is the working code sample:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.common import SetOfString
from ibapi.common import SetOfFloat
from threading import Timer

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):

        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):

        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):

        self.start()
        # pass

    def securityDefinitionOptionParameter(self, reqId:int, exchange:str, underlyingConId:int, tradingClass:str, multiplier:str, expirations:SetOfString, strikes:SetOfFloat):
        print("SecurityDefinitionOptionParameter.", "ReqId:", reqId, "Exchange:", exchange, "Underlying conId:", underlyingConId, "TradingClass:", tradingClass, "Multiplier:", multiplier, "Expirations:", expirations, "Strikes:", str(strikes),"\n")

    def securityDefinitionOptionParameterEnd(self, reqId:int):

        print("SecurityDefinitionOptionParameterEnd. ReqId:", reqId)

    def start(self):

        # 265598 is the conId (contract ID) for AAPL Nasdaq stock
        self.reqSecDefOptParams(1, "AAPL", "", "STK", 265598)

    def stop(self):

        self.done = True
        self.disconnect()

def main():

    app = TestApp()
    app.nextOrderId = 0
    # TWs 7497, IBGW 4001
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0)

    Timer(4, app.stop).start()
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. The API functions are asynchronous since they send messages across a network. In general it would be very inefficient to have synchronous, 'blocking' functions that take an input such as "AAPL", block further execution of the program while waiting on a response from the server, and then return a result when it is received. So instead the functions send a message and return immediately so that other tasks can be performed while waiting on a response.

   There are however frameworks such as [ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync) which use the Python [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module designed for concurrent code, and can make the execution flow look more sequential from top to bottom, and only stop to wait for a response when it is necessary to proceed.
2. The contract ID can be obtained with the function [reqContractDetails](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/contract_details.html) if you define a Contract object with the symbol, exchange, security type, and currency. There should be an example of this function in the 
   [Traders Academy Course](https://ndcdyn.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=25243) as well (the short videos also on Youtube).